# Application Roles are not showing up in the Identity Manager - OBIEE12c

Tags: obiee

I'm trying to do the Data Access Security in OBIEE.

I have done the Following :

1. Created the User in the Enterprise Manager .
2. Assigned all the groups to the user .
3. Connected the RPD Online .
4. To implement the Data Access Security :
   Manage > Identity ( Identity Manager ) where the Application Roles Tab is empty (No Application Roles were present ) but The users are Showing up .

[image]

The synchronize application roles(Identity Manager -> Action -> Synchronize Application Roles)is not showing.

[image]

The information about admin tool as below

[image]

Please help me on above.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity Manager -> Action -> Synchronize Application Roles

Edit: You are running an outdated and unsupported version. Update to something supported. You are wasting your time looking at things which were fixed ages ago.

Edit 2: If you really want to stay on old technology, then go for 12.2.1.4 with the latest bundle patch.
OBIEE is being replaced with Oracle Analytics Server which is currently at version 5.5: https://www.oracle.com/solutions/business-analytics/analytics-server/analytics-server.html

Comment: thanks for your response, Synchronize Application Roles is not showing, please check the updates question.

Comment: What precise version of the Admin Tool is this?

Comment: Please find the updated question, where I attached the snap shot of Admin tool version.

Comment: Obvious question: What version of OBIEE are you really running on the server?

Comment: we are running OBIEE version 12.2.1.0.0 on server.

Comment: thanks for the update can you suggest any specific version, 12 series, Since I'm new user of OBIEE.

Comment: Updated answer above so you can close this

Comment: thanks for your information one last query can we use version 12.2.1.4 or 12.2.1.2 because I'm facing a issue on uploading RPD on 12.2.1.4

Comment: The proper way is to check WHY you have that issue, resolve it and then use 12.2.1.4. As I said, OBIEE is being replaced with OAS so you're anyways on something outdated if you stay on 12.2.1.4.